# Python's Multiprocessing Pipes aren't working

Tags: android, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pipe

I have the following very small bit of code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pipe
End1, End2 = Pipe ()
```

Which yielded the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/storage/sdcard0/MyMovie/.run/.last_tmp.py", line 3, in <module>
End1, End2 = Pipe ()
File "/storage/sdcard0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/lib/python3.2/site-packages/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 106, in Pipe
return Pipe(duplex)
File "/storage/sdcard0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/lib/python3.2/site-packages/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 188, in Pipe
s1, s2 = socket.socketpair()
File "/storage/sdcard0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/lib/python3.2/site-packages/socket.py", line 225, in socketpair
a, b = _socket.socketpair(family, type, proto)
socket.error: [Errno 95] Operation not supported on transport endpoint
```

I goggled the last error, but couldn't find anything useful. I've seen it used just like this in the documentation, so I can't see it being what I wrote, given its only 2 lines. Could this be an "internal problem"?
I'm using the Python3 Interpreter for Android, using Python 3.2

Thank you

Comment: I thought the error might be because I ended the program with "cleaning up/closing" the pipe, but that's not the case. It crashes the second I try to construct the pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the hardware support multiprocessing? I am not sure, but it might be the problem.

Comment: Does multithreading support == multiprocessing support? I tried the queues so I assumed it worked, but thinking back, I think those were multithreading queues. I know MT works, but I've never tested MP. Is there a reliable way to test for compatability? I don't know where I'd check on the Android system. I've never heard it being explicitly incompatible.

Comment: I tried using a multiprocessing Queue, and got the error "Errno 38: Function not implemented", which is more descriptive then the other error. I think you might (unfortunately) be right.

Comment: Isn't a semaphore the most basic of locks? Isn't it just a value that gets incremented/decremented, and unlocks when it's value is 0? How could android not have that, but have other locks? Just seems weird.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. I've moved on since then, and found out that Twisted isn't compatible with my table's processor, and pyserial doesn't like my version of 2to3 -_-